# c xor result is different than javascript xor

Tags: javascript, c, encryption, xor

I'm trying to do some sort of xor file encryption in c, and decryption in javascript (using [this](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/48889-c-tutorial-xor-encryption/) as a basis, and for now I'm stuck at the following issue:

Say for example i want to do `73^122` in C, the result is `57`, but the same operation in javascript yields `51`. Why is this happening, and what would be the proper way to fix it?

Here's some C code of the encrypt function

```
void encrypt_data(FILE* input_file, FILE* output_file, char* key)
{
  int key_count = 0; //Used to restart key if strlen(key) < strlen(encrypt)
  int encrypt_byte;

  while( (encrypt_byte = fgetc(input_file)) != EOF) //Loop through each byte of file until EOF
  {
    //XOR the data and write it to a file
    fputc(encrypt_byte ^ key[key_count], output_file);
    printf("original %d\n", encrypt_byte); //yields 73
    printf("xoring with %d\n", key[key_count]); // yields 122
    printf("xored %d\n", encrypt_byte ^ key[key_count]); // yields 57
    break; //breaking just for example purpose

    //Increment key_count and start over if necessary
    key_count++;
    if(key_count == strlen(key))
        key_count = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting 57 in C for the operation 73^122?

Comment: I'm also doing a `printf("test %d\n", 73^112);` and get a 57. Am i printing with the wrong specifier?

Comment: http://ideone.com/5c3dNz

Comment: Maybe your font's 7 looks like a 1? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: and I found the problem, I was doing a typo, in c was 73^112, in js was 73^122 (or the other way around)

Comment: stating a problem that isn't really a problem. please close

Comment: You can review your result here: th-thielemann.de/tools/checksum.html

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt the result for C that you're mentioning. You should show some code.

That your right-hand side has more than 8 bits is a bit strange, normally for XOR encryption in C you'd do it one `char` at a time, which in practice means with 8-bit bytes.

Any chance you confused hexadecimal (`0x73` and `0x122`) vs decimal (`73` and `122`) number literals? Again, very hard to help when you're not showing your code.

Comment: 0x73 ^ 0x122 = 0x151 or 337

Answer (score 1):

When I run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", 73^122);
}
```

I get:

```
51
```

can you please show us the C code in question and we can show you the bug.

Comment: As it would/should be everywhere. This is like saying `1 + 1 != 2` in C while it is in Javascript...